# Why doesn't the for loop stop on les then operator (<) but continues to loop one more time to be (=) to 5

Tags: javascript, for-loop

The operator is les then or equal. So why does it continue to loop one more time since when it looped 4 times, it reached one of it's conditions?

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  console.log("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: Because you're not using the `<` operator

Comment: 0 1 2 3 4 5, that's six times?

Comment: When you use this `<=` you're saying less than or equal to, or 5, try using `<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `<=` means less than or equal, but I believe you are confusing how loops work. The second statement in a for-loop declaration is called the condition, and defines when a loop can continue to execute. If the condition returns true, the loop body is executed. If false, it breaks.

If it helps, you can imagine it as a while loop where

```
for(declaration; condition; increment) 
{
    //loop body
}
```

is fundamentally equivalent to

```
declaration;
while(condition)
{
    //loop body
    increment;
}
```

A condition of `i <= 5` means the loop will continue to execute as long as the `i` is less than or equal to 5. It does not mean the loop will break if `i` is no longer both less than nor equal to 5.

The simple change is to use `i < 5`.

Comment: Thank you David,
I think i understand now :)

Answer (score 1):

The `i <= 5` condition has to evaluate to false for the control to break the loop.  And that happens when the value of i is 6.

Answer (score -2):

because you start with zero or use <5 instead of <= if i=0

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  console.log("Hello World!");
}
```